Probability of no empty bins when $n$ balls go into $3$ bins
I'm a bit unsure what's wrong with my reasoning here:
So we have $n$ balls, and want to place them into 3 bins, and we want the probability that $0$ bins are empty.
Numerator: number of ways that $0$ bins are empty
Denominator: number of ways that we can allocate the balls
Let's first take $3$ balls, and put them into $3$ different bins. So we have $nC3$ ways of picking $3$ balls, and then $3!$ ways of placing them into 3 different bins. Great, so now, every bin has a ball in it. So now, we can just place the remaining $n-3$ balls however we want, which can happen $3^{n-3}$ ways.
Numerator: $nC3 * 3! * 3^{n-3}$
Denominator: $3^n$
What's wrong with my logic?

Your numerator overcounts the total possible configurations. For a concrete example, take $N=4$. I am going to introduce some notation to describe your procedure.
Let:

$S$ be the set from your first selection of 3 balls;
$V$ be the permutation telling you which bins they are in; and
$W$ be the position of the remaining ball.

Your method would work if there were a bijection between desired configurations and values of $(S, V, W)$. However this is not the case.
Consider:
$$S = \{1,2,3\} \quad V = (1,2,3) \quad W = 1$$
Verbally: choosing balls 1,2,3; putting them respectively in bins 1, 2, 3; and putting the remaining ball (number 4) in bin 1. And:
$$S' = \{2,3,4\} \quad V' = (2,3,1) \quad W' = 1$$
Verbally: choosing balls 2,3,4; putting them respectively in bins 2, 3, 1; and putting the remaining ball (number 1) in bin 1.
The two distinct values $(S,V,W)$ and $(S',V',W')$ correspond to the same configuration, with balls 1 and 4 in bin 1, ball 2 in bin 3, and ball 3 in bin 3. However, they are both counted in your numerator.

From your attempt, it is clear that the problem is about placing distinct balls into distinct bins
Whenever you fractionate choices/placements, you will overcount.
In your process, for example, you place balls A,B,C in the first lot in boxes $1,2,3$ then place the rest. But on another placement, you might have placed D,E,F in boxes $1,2,3$ but again placed one or more of A,B,C in the way you had placed them in the first placement.
You cam look up fractionate on this site for more explanations of this error, which us made all too frequently.
The correct way to do it is to use inclusion-exclusion, thus
All ways - one bin guaranteed empty + two bins guaranteed empty
$$= 3^n - \binom31 2^n + \binom 32 1^n$$
For $n=6$ for example, it would be
$$3^6 -3\cdot2^6 + 3\cdot1^6 = 540$$
And if you have been taught Stirling numbers of the second kind which places distinct  objects into identical non-empty bins, just $3!{6\brace3}$
So for your general problem, $\;\;3!{n\brace 3}$
